# How to pass as variable a composite region?

Tags: imagemagick

I'm running this command (in ImageMagick 7.0.10-61 Q16 under cygwin)

```
convert input.png -crop 100x50+20+80 +repage \( -size 15x10 xc:white \) -geometry +20+0 -composite output.png
```

and works fine. Now I want to include the "white region" as variable since depends of a previous `if` control block. I'm doing in the way shown below, and even the output image is generated I get those errors. How to fix this? Thanks in advance

```
white_region=" \( -size 15x10 xc:white \) -geometry +20+0 -composite "

$ convert input.png -crop 100x50+20+80 +repage ${white_region} output.png
convert: unable to open image '\(': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/3537.
convert: no decode delegate for this image format `' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/572.
convert: unable to open image '\)': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/3537.
convert: unable to open image '\)': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/3537.
convert: no decode delegate for this image format `' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/572.
```

**UPDATE 1**

Having these 2 input images in a folder. One image with a width of 335px and the other with a width of 480px. For images with w=335px apply one `white_region` else apply another `white_region`

[image: Input1.png] [image: Input2.png]

If I run this script I get output correctly:

```
for image in *.png; do
    w=$(identify -ping -format '%w' $image)
    
    if [ $w == 335 ]; then
        h=192
        convert ${image} -crop ${w}x${h}+0+0 +repage \( -size 120x25 xc:white \) -geometry +0+0 -composite out_${image}
    else
        h=232
        convert ${image} -crop ${w}x${h}+0+0 +repage \( -size 130x15 xc:white \) -geometry +0+0 -composite \( -size 140x50 xc:white \) -geometry +340+0 -composite out_${image}
    fi
done
```

But if I use the `white_region` variable I get errors.

```
for image in *.png; do
    w=$(identify -ping -format '%w' $image)
    
    if [ $w == 335 ]; then
        white_region="\( -size 120x25 xc:white \) -geometry 0+0 -composite"
        h=192
    else
        white_region="\( -size 130x15 xc:white \) -geometry 0+0 -composite \( -size 140x50 xc:white \) -geometry +340+0 -composite "
        h=232
    fi
    
    convert ${image} -crop ${w}x${h}+0+0 +repage ${white_region} out_${image}
done
```

**UPDATE 2**

This is the way that worked for me without escaped parentheses. Thanks all for the help

```
for image in im*.png; do
    w=$(identify -ping -format '%w' $image)
    
    if [ $w == 335 ]; then
        white_region="-size 120x25 xc:white -geometry +0+0 -composite"
        h=192
    else
        white_region="-size 130x15 xc:white -geometry +0+0 -composite -size 140x50 xc:white -geometry +340+0 -composite"
        h=232
    fi
    
    convert ${image} -crop ${w}x${h}+0+0 ${white_region} out_${image}
done
```

Comment: In what way does the white region depend upon a previous "if" condition?  You cannot put escaped parentheses in quotes.  So I need to understand what exactly you are trying to do.  What are you trying to vary?

Comment: The white region is of different size and goes in different position depending the size of input image I process. Since is part of a larger bash program, the content of `white_region` is constructed before the `convert` command. So, for what you say is a syntax issue?

Comment: ImageMagick can do some pretty sophisticated conditional processing within the IM command itself. Provide a more specific description/examples of the possibilities you expect to encounter, and there may be IM commands that get a lot of the work done.

Comment: @GeeMack I've updated my original post with a smaller version of the actual script with what I'm trying to do. Thanks in advance

Comment: Don't try to make a variable for the whole thing you are trying to do.  Just make variables for the width, height and offset X and Y, each.  Then you can substitute them into your command.

Comment: If on IM 6, you can set individual variables and substitute into your second command.  So for example: white1="-size 120x25 xc:white" and white2="" and geom1="+0+0" and comp1="-composite" and comp2="" and geom2="" for case 335 and white1="-size 130x15 xc:white" and white2="-size 140x50 xc:white" and geom2="+340+0" and comp1="-composite" and comp2="-composite".  Now substitute those variable in your second conditional command as one command.  Or if on IM 7, do as  GMack suggested with conditionals in-line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parentheses and backslash-escaping of them are unnecessary in your command. You only need parentheses when you want **ImageMagick** to only apply an *"operator"* to a single image, rather than all images in a stack.

This loads "image1.png" and then "image2.png" and crops both:

```
magick image1.png image2.png -crop 10x10+0+0 ....
```

This loads the same two images, but only crops the first:

```
magick image1.png -crop 10x10+0+0 image2.png ...
```

And this loads the same two images, but crops only the second:

```
magick image1.png \( image2.png -crop 10x10+0+0 \) ...
```

However, you are not applying an *"operator"* like `-crop` but rather a *"setting"* of `-size` which doesn't operate on any images but just sets a parameter that may affect future operators. As such, you don't need parentheses.

---

So you can use commands like this:

```
partA="-size 80x80 xc:red +append"
partB="-size 160x80 xc:lime +append"
magick -size 80x80 xc:blue $partA $partB result.jpg
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation and examples. I've updated my original (below update 2) post showing the way it works for me, I think following the logic you mention without escaped parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

This command is in Windows CLI syntax, and uses ImageMagick v7 emulating IMv6 (magick convert...). It should be fairly simple to modify for a *nix shell script...

```
magick convert %FILENAME% ^
   -set option:distort:viewport "%[w]x%[fx:w==335?192:232]" -distort SRT 0 ^
   -set option:distort:viewport "%[fx:w==335?120:130]x%[fx:w==335?25:15]" ^
   ( +clone -evaluate set 100% -distort SRT 0 ) -composite +repage "out_%FILENAME%"
```

That reads the filename from a variable which could easily be sent into the command from a "for" loop.

Then it specifies the viewport size to 335x192 or 480x232 depending on the input width. The no-op "-distort" operation changes the viewport as necessary, the equivalent of your "-crop".

Then it specifies a viewport size of 120x25 or 130x15, again depending on the input width.

The tricky part, next it clones the input image inside parentheses, changes it to all white with "-evaluate set 100%", and uses a no-op "-distort" to change its viewport according to the viewport setting previously applied.

After the parentheses it composites that cropped white image on the cropped input image, and uses the input filename to create an output name.

To run this on IMv6 in a *nix shell it will require removing "magick" from the beginning of the command, changing the syntax of the "%FILENAME%" variable, changing the continued-line carets "^" to backslashes "\", and escaping the parentheses with backslashes "\(...\)". I haven't tested it, but that should be very close to correct.

Comment: Thanks for the different approach to do this and for the explanation., since still I'm confuse how operates the part between `viewport` and `-distort`, even I can identify you put inside an `if condition`. Additionally, I've included your solution within a for loop and the output is correct only for first image processed. Basically the variable white_regions are to remove the `logo and the "Textbook"` for first image and remove the rocket and text to the rigth for second image.

Comment: Using "-set option:distort:viewport" essentially adds a variable to the image that means "next time there's a '-distort' operation, make the canvas these dimensions". Although a "-distort" operation can take many options and do many things, in this command, the "-distort SRT 0" does nothing except change the canvas size, or basically crop where needed.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I've been searching information about how to understand/use/construct this kind of expressions `"%[w]x%[fx:w..]` but only have found `FX effects` that not seem to be the same thing.

Comment: A detailed description of the variables and functions you can use inside %[fx:...] expressions can be found here... https://imagemagick.org/script/fx.php